# How to Add a relationship between two nodes using Neo4jClient with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

```
public void AddRelationshipTest()
    {
        var conn = Neo4JConn.Connect();
        Team obj = new Team();
        int id1 = 1, id2 = 2;
        NodeReference<Team> sTm = (NodeReference<Team>)ds.GetNodeReference<Team>(id1, conn, obj);
        NodeReference<Team> dTm = (NodeReference<Team>)ds.GetNodeReference<Team>(id2, conn, obj);

        ReportsToData data = new ReportsToData();
        data.SinceYear = 2008;
        reportsTo relation = new reportsTo(dTm, data);
        conn.CreateRelationship(sTm, relation);



    }
```

where Get NodeRefernce is a method which returns reference of the node and that is working fine. Team is the class having  data members as of the nodes
When i  am using CreateRelationship it creates a relationship 
My main concern is that it creates relationship even if there is a relationship already between source and target node.
I want to create a unique relationship in between two nodes just like

```
graphClient.Cypher
.Match("(user1:User)", "(user2:User)")
.Where((User user1) => user1.Id == 123)
.AndWhere((User user2) => user2.Id == 456)
.CreateUnique("user1-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->user2")
.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

but here FRIENDS_WITH (any relationship) I have to hard code it so i don't want to use it.

How to do it with Neo4jClient?

Comment: When you're banned from asking new questions, **do not** rewrite old questions in their stead. Read [the advisory](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/476) and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the problem is, with the `.CreateUnique` why not just use `string.Format` or string interpolation to not hard code the relationship?

```
public void CreateRelationship(IGraphClient graphClient, string relationshipName)
{
    graphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(user1:User)", "(user2:User)")
        .Where((User user1) => user1.Id == 123)
        .AndWhere((User user2) => user2.Id == 456)
        .CreateUnique($"(user1)-[:{relationshipName}]->(user2)") //<-- here
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
}
```

obviously that could be:

`.CreateUnique(string.Format("(user1)-[:{0}]->(user2)", relationshipName))`

or even just use `+` if you really want:

`.CreateUnique("(user1)-[:" + relationshipName + "]->(user2)")`

You **should** definitely be using the Cypher technique though, and *not* using `NodeReference<T>`